# Swap page content in javascript. Why isn't there a solution for this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, node-webkit, electron

I'm wondering if there really isn't a single ***practical*** solution to this problem.  Namely, swapping html content of webpages.

In this case [jquery's load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) isn't useful because I have to load the file **locally** for **Node-webkit** which isn't working because [Cross origin requests](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) are not allowed on chrome.
And I just won't create a frigging localhost webserver just to load a local piece of html.

Basically my problem is that if I link to other html files in the menu-bar, the entire javascript reloads too, that makes it impossible to keep processes running without interruption in the background. If the Html page reloads ***everything including Javascript files reload.*** Killing the current processes of Node-webkit Node Js etc.

Here a piece of code just to illustrate what I **don't** want to do.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("this task can't be interrupted!");
    }, 3000);
    </script>
    <script src="more_important_js_tasks_running_here.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul class="pure-menu-list">
            <li><a href="file1.html">If I click here I will kill my javascript task 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="file2.html">If I click here I will kill my javascript task 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="file3.html">If I click here I will kill my javascript task 3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="this is the content I would like to change.. maybe 100 lines of code or whatever">


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I could put everything into a string, and do

`document.body.innerHTML = "<p>whatever</p>”`;

but this isn't practical because there is no nice way to put everything into one line. Codifying everything into one line also can accidentally go wrong.. Something inevitable with a large string of html.

`document.body.innerHTML = "<p class="p">If this happens it will break</p>";`

Multi-line strings aren't a good option either

```
var str = "Javascript \ 
    multi-line \
    strings \
    are \
    awful";
```

No easy way to copy-paste your code into that and this code could break because of one whitespace after any of the escape characters. Maybe concatenation?

```
var a = "hey man, this is on a line\n" + 
        "and this is on another\n" +
        "and this is on a third";
```

Good luck concatenating manually your 300 lines html file like this.
At least [there is a better way to do this in ES6.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

Perhaps I could use something like [node-htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) and read/parse the entire file.. but still there is the problem of getting that whole piece into the DOM.

```
fs.createReadStream('./path_to_file.html').pipe(parser);
```

Is there no simple, standart pure-javascript way to swap content locally without crazy hacks or external libraries? Wasn't the web designed for this and isn't there a need to implement some solution for this in these days where tools like [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) and [NW](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) are becoming more and more popular for desktop application development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are locally and contain HTML, you could use the Node FileSystem module to load the file then set the content as the inner HTML of a DOM object - no external libraries required.

I've extended your example below. I've used the synchronous API, but you could just as easily use the async. Note that "Page loaded" appears once, and your timer continues to execute in the background. Make sure the files are in the same directory as the main page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("this task can't be interrupted!");
    }, 3000);

    function loadPage(fileName)
    {
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, data)
        {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data);

            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data;
        });
    }
    alert("Page loaded");
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadPage('page1.html')">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadPage('page2.html')">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="content" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with using this in Node-webkit but I do know that performing an AJAX request if you're loading a file:// url usually will throw a CORS error. AJAX isn't designed to work on the file system, it's designed to work over a network thus implementing a simple web server in your app is probably the simplest solution.

An alternative would be to create a "build" method that interpolates the content of each of your page templates into the main template then load that instead. That way you could just use jQuery to replace the content of your content div and you'd be all good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing different things.

When you are using node.js you are on the server side. That means that you will send something to a browser or another app and you will get answers. For this you are defining events. If you want send events to the browser from your server you have to define some listeners there.

If you have a webpage you can also include some jQuery, which the browser will interprete at the client side. If you want that html content changes, when the user clicks a link you should use jQuery (at the client). With jQuery you can also define, which elements of another page are loaded.

Another way, which you could use also with Electron would be JSON files. There you can define longer textes. You can load them at the browser and you can easiely import them with node.js via require. You can also use one JSON file, which defines which other JSON files you want to load.

But you should think about that a electron app is based on web technology, but it is not a local webserver or local webpage. Because you can directly communicate to the node.js over the html view that is something totally different.